# Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be a finite open cover for $X$. Then for $\varepsilon > 0$ every $x \in X, B(x,\varepsilon)$ is contained in one of $U_\alpha$’s.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be a finite open cover for $X$. show there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every $x \in X, B(x,\varepsilon)$ is contained in one of the $U_\alpha$’s.

Since $X = U_{\alpha_1} \cup \dots \cup U_{\alpha_k}$ picking $x \in X$ I have that $x \in U_{\alpha_1}$ or $x \in U_{\alpha_2}$,... generally $x$ will be in one of the $U_\alpha$’s.

Since each of the $U_{\alpha_i}$ are open there exits one containing $x$ and by the openness there exist $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x, \varepsilon)$ is containded in it. Is the idea here right or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you be more precise with your quantifiers?

Comment: I’m writing on phone so I will be correcting this when I get on the laptop

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma).